# Formulate a likelihood function for an uncertain discrete "n", where y is binom(n,p), and we know y and p

Tags: binomial-distribution, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

The problem goes as followed: multiple balls have been tossed into a box, but we do not know how many that were tossed. However, we know that 5 of the balls that were tossed had a blue colour ($y=5$), and that the probability $p$ of tossing a blue ball is 30%. We also know that \begin{align} y \sim Bin(n,p) \end{align}

Thereby, my question is: how should the likelihood function, $L(n|y=5,p=0.30)$, be formulated, and how should I go about deriving the maximum likelihood estimate of $n$ in this setting, where $n$ is discrete?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: For each $n$, compute the probability that you threw $5$ blues in.  Maximize the result in $n$.  Note:  it is not clear to me whether you meant *exactly* five or *at least* five.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time, @lulu. I meant exactly 5. However, it is still not fully clear to me what to do. I would set up: $P(y=5) = \binom{n}{5} \cdot 0.3^{5} \cdot (1-0.3)^{n-5}$, but this would imply taking derivatives of a factorial.. is that the only way to go about this?

Comment: No need for a derivative.  Just list the values and pick the max.  Note:  you ought to be able to guess the answer fairly closely (though what I think is the most natural guess is in fact off by $1$).